# how to pass a variable in attribute value while creating it in typescript

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, object, typescript

```
this.listvalue;
list.forEach((v: any) => {

  v.data.forEach((v2: any) => {


    this.searchlist.push({
      header: v.header,
      value: v2.value_0

    });
  });
});
```

i want to pass the `this.listvalue` on the place of `v2.value_0 =>v2.this.listvalue` but this is not working giving syntax error I also tried `v2.valueof(this.listvalue)` but its also not working like that i want to change call the v2 via `this.listvalue`

> How can I do this? what is the correct syntax for this scenario?
>   the whole code is here

```
export class Md2Component {
  @Input() list: any;
  @Input() listvalue: any;

  public searchlist;
  public placeholder: String = "Searct the JSON";
  public switch: boolean = true;
  public switch5: boolean = true;
  public searchlistresult: any
  public data: string;
  public header1: String;
  public resultant_list: any;
  public lastone: user[] = [];
  @Output() _onSelect = new EventEmitter<any>();
  public anyinstance: any
  public user2: user

  s = '';
  public index;

  constructor() {

  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.data = this.listvalue;
    this.createSearchList(this.list);
    this.latest(this.searchlist);

  }
  private createSearchList(list: any) {
    this.searchlist = [];
    this.listvalue;
    list.forEach((v: any) => {
      v.data.forEach((v2: any) => {
        this.searchlist.push({
          header: v.header,
          value: v2.value_0

        });
      });
    });



  }
  search1(s) {
    this.search(s);
    if (this.switch != true) {
      this.latest(this.searchlistresult)
    }
  }

  search(s) {
    this.switch = false;

    this.searchlistresult = _.filter(this.searchlist, (o: any) => {
      if (s) {

        return _.startsWith(_.lowerCase(o.value), _.lowerCase(s));
      }
      this.switch = true;
      return true;
    });
  }
  latest(list: any) {

    const arr = list;

    const keys = [];

    for (let i of arr) {
      if (!keys.includes(i.header)) keys.push(i.header);
    }

    const result = keys
      .map(k => Object.assign({header: k}, {
        data: arr.filter(x => x.header === k)
          .map(y => Object.assign({}, {value: y.value}))
      }));
    this.anyinstance = result;



  }
  generateArray(obj) {
    return Object.keys(obj).map((key) => {return obj[key]});
  }
  onSelect(header: any, value: any) {
    {
      console.log(header);
      console.log(value);
      this.s = value;
      this.user2 = {
        header: header,
        value: value
      }
      this.lastone.push({
        'header': header,
        'value': value,
      }
      );
      this.switch = true;
      this._onSelect.emit(this.user2);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you add full code file.. it seems like you might not declared `listvalue` correctly

Comment: ` @Input() listvalue:any;` this is on the top of my code i think it declared

Comment: `   private createSearchList(list: any) {
    this.searchlist = [];
    this.listvalue;
    list.forEach((v: any) => {
      v.data.forEach((v2: any) => {
        this.searchlist.push({
          header:v.header,
          value:v2.value_0

        });
      });
    });
  } `

Comment: nothing happen after remove it

Comment: what ever you have please update your question with code..

Comment: @HASSANMEHMOOD you never seem to initialize `this.listvalue` with any value. You also never access it anywhere else in the function. Are you trying to assign `v2.value_0` to be `this.listvalue` ??

Comment: i tried but its not working in thats why i not wrote that in my code i want to replace v2.value_0 with v2.this.listvalue

Comment: @James   
you got me wrong ... i dont want to assign the listvalue in V2.value_0 . Actually i want to call that attritube in v2 that is in listvalue like v2.this.listvalue

Answer (score 0):

You've said `this.listvalue` is an `@Input()` so we will assume it has been initialized with a value already.

**UPDATE** You can try passing as a parameter. As the global scope of `listvalue` is what's causing your issue, passing it into the function will bring it into the correct scope.

```
// Bringing listvalue into scope, to avoid use of 'this' accessor.
private createSearchList(list: any, listvalue: any) { 
    this.searchlist = []; 

    list.forEach((v: any) => { 
        v.data.forEach((v2: any) => { 

            this.searchlist.push({ 
                header: v.header, 
                value: listvalue
            }); 
        }); 
    }); 
 }
```

Comment: you got me wrong ... i dont want to assign the listvalue in V2.value_0 . Actually i want to call that attritube in v2 that is in listvalue like v2.this.listvalue

Comment: @HASSANMEHMOOD you should be able to do this using `v2.listvalue` no?

Comment: but the list value is out of the function and ihave to call it via this.listvalue

Comment: Did `value: v2[this.listvalue]` work for you, or not? You can, alternatively, pass the correct `listvalue` as a parameter to this function to bring it into scope.